# angularjs http post method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

Trying to post something back to the mongodb however its not sending anything, when I click submit its passing {} back to the cmd and the network console is hanging on pending then it will fail when its taking long to post.

Can someone shed a light on this one please, thanks.

Html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.user">
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.pass">
```

Service:

```
function _postUser(user,pass){
        var params = {
            user: user,
            pass:pass
        }
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/loginDB',
            params: params
        })
    }
```

Get users: I get the users from the DB.

```
vm.getUsers = function (){
        homeService.getUsers()
            .then(function(response){
                vm.users = response.data;
                console.log(vm.users);
            });
    }
```

Post action:

```
vm.postUser = function() {
        // console.log('send it back')
        homeService.postUser(vm.user)
            .then(function(response){
                console.log('send it back')
            })
    }
```

Server.js app.post back to db

```
app.post('/loginDB', function (req, res){
console.log(req.body);
});
```

Edit: its posting but now taking the ng-model, I know something is wrong with the ng-model but just can't get my head on it.

```
db.loginDB.insert(req.body, function(err, doc){
    res.json(doc);
})
```

Comment: what's in the req.body since you got it at the server?

Comment: @HarryLim its only giving me the user in req.body, payload is only using user that';s being pass.

Comment: so no password just username ? did you do something wrong on the ng-click or ng-submit ?

Comment: i think I just fixed it, I was only passing vm.user in the post request. Fixed it by homeService.postUser(vm.user, vm.pass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `params` key to `data`

```
 return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/loginDB',
        data: params
    })
```

In the html too you have the same model for both the inputs,

controller declaration,

```
vm.newuser = {user:'',pass:''};
```

html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.newuser.user">
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.newuser.pass">
```

Comment: still the same tho, its not taking the input to send it back to db

Comment: Can you show me where you assign the model to scope

Comment: what I put in my original post is all I have.

Comment: Are you assigning the `newuser` object to vm, if yes does it have two keys `user` and `pass`

Comment: well sorry that was my typo, yes it will be vm.userand vm.pass. Which I have in the service as well inside params. it seems to be passing the user but not the pass.

Comment: it will be vm.user and vm.pass, I did your edit earlier before I post it here its only clearing the input than saving it.

Comment: you should pass `vm.pass` also to service, did you change `params` to `data`

Comment: yeah i think i've fixed it now